# How to dont let users save the same item twice in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache

In my php/mysql app I let users save items eg: "add to list"

How should I structure the table to prevent users from saving the same item twice?

For now my table looks like

**id** - primary key, incrementing

**u_id** - foreign key, links to users primary key in users table

**i_id** - foreign key, links to items primary key in items table

So can I structure my table in order to prevent users from saving the same item twice? Or do I have to do that checkup before making the save/insert query?

Comment: Both approaches are possible, if you do it inside the database, then you have to do error checking on php level. But that has to be done anyway, so... I suggest you add a unique index to the columns where no entry should occur twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want a unique index (or unique constraint which is the same thing) on the two columns:

```
create unique index idx_mytable_u_i on (u_id, i_id)
```

The database will then guarantee that duplicates are not inserted.